# IOS - remove all '\' from Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have store all value in string and after that

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [dict setValue:@"10004" forKey:@"acid"];
        [dict setValue:cleanedString forKey:@"registration-info"];
```

But when we print:-

```
{
        acid = 10004;
        "registration-info" = "[{\"q9\":\"AB\",\"q16\":\"ABC\",\"q1\":\"AB\",\"q20\":\"ABCD\",\"q2\":\"Thinking, Watching T.V.\",\"q12\":\"AB\",\"q17\":\"AB\",\"q3\":\"Job, Money, Family.\",\"q21\":\"c, Number of days: 20\",\"q13\":\"ABCD\",\"q4\":\"Job, Money..\",\"q18\":\"AB\",\"q5\":\"Job, Money, Family..\",\"q14\":\"Earning More Money\",\"email\":\"U10022@satanclause.it\",\"q6\":\"A\",\"q19\":\"AB\",\"q10\":\"Poorness..\",\"q7\":\"Thinking, \",\"q15\":\"Poorness..\",\"password\":\"Please write a password\",\"q8\":\"AB\",\"q11\":\"Loss..\"}]";
    }
```

I want to remove all \ in this dictionary.Can anybody help me..

Comment: That's JSON, have you considered parsing it?

Comment: Yes, i have set all value in NSDictionary and after that i store dictionary into the array. 
And after that i used below code:-

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr 
                                                    options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString;
    if (jsonData) {
        jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
       
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
        jsonString = @"";
    }

Comment: reference- NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [myString 
   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"" withString:@"\"];

Comment: I have check using your reference. but It's not working....

Comment: First of all don't use `setValue:forKey:` unless you really need KVC (you don't need it at all in this case). It's `setObject:forKey:`. Second of all you don't need to change anything. The escaped quotes appear only in the string representation of the dictionary.

Comment: I have used now:-
[dict setObject:@"10004" forKey:@"acid"];
[dict setObject:jsonString forKey:@"registration-info"];

But i have same output after print. \ is not removed.

Comment: Once again, the backslashes appear only in the print output. They don't exist actually.